# 2GP Package Creation - Email Template include error

Tags: package, unlocked-package, 2gp

i have created a 2gp package which contains email template from public classic email template folder. But while installing package it throws error as below
[image]

Answer (score 2):

We cannot use public folder. Please create a folder with public access and try to create and install the package.

Folder metadata can look like below-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <name>New_Folder</name>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadWrite</publicFolderAccess>
</EmailFolder>
```